# Django database discrepency

Tags: django, django-models

I have got a django based website with a user authentication system. There is model (say A) with an attribute filename which has to be unique. On clicking a certain button on a web page, one of the python views does the following

```
file=randomNameX()
a=A(filename=file) 
a.save()

def randomStringX(length):
    s = ''
    letters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    while len(s) < length:
    s += letters[random.randint(0, len(letters)-1)]
    return s

def randomNameX():
    name = randomString(10)
    while A.objects.filter(filename="_"+name).count() > 0:
    name = randomString(10)
    return name
```

Is it possible that two users (user 1 and user 2) might generate the same filename at the same time and the database entry happens first for user 1 and since the attribute is unique, an exception is raised for user 2?

If yes, please tell me how to overcome this.

Comment: how about showing your actual code? Can filenames be sequential (like file1, file2,..file10 etc)? what is the purpose of creating these files? sessions? avatars? how far did you go until now?

Comment: filename is always randomly generated .The 'file' variable is a string for the attribute filename in the table

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is called a race condition (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

Whether this can happen with your current code or not depends on the implementation of "generate a random filename" so only you can tell the answer, but the simplest way to avoid such a problem is to use some UUID system (http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Unique_Identifier), either a standard one or a "roll your own" solution.

Given the context (a HTTP request handler), a combination of a timestamp, the request client's IP address AND some random stuff should be enough to greatly reduce the probability of such a collision.

Comment: @RuppeshNalwaya : your solution will end up in a race condition one day or another (assuming anyone is using your app of course - no user, no bug <g>). Don't waste your time reinventing the SquaredWheel(tm) when there are known working solutions (cf my answer).